# Handle the combination of delimited and non delimited columns to get new row of corresponding value

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

For a certain scenario wherein a PySpark DataFrame is created where two columns are `pipe` delimited and one column is not but is the aggregation of the both the other ones(pipe delimited):

```
product quantity revenue
a|b      1|1       3          #this means product 'a' quantity was 1 and 'b' was also 1 and total revenue came out to be 3 for both the products
b|c      3|2       9          #this means product 'b' quantity was 3 and 'c' was also 2 and total revenue came out to be 9 for all 5 products
```

Since my `product` and `quantity` column are pipe delimited I separated each product and its quantity and exploded it to get the individual quantity like this:

```
product   quantity
a            1
b            1
b            3
c            2
```

But since I do not have revenue delimited so currently I just append zeros in that column but what I am trying to get is something like this (where revenue comes in another row of `product` hardcoded as `no delimiter in rev`

```
product           quantity  revenue
a                    1        0
b                    1        0
no delimiter in rev  0        3
b                    3        0
c                    2        0
no delimiter in rev  0        9
```

Any insights on how to achieve it would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `union` the original data frame with product column set as `no delimiter in rev` with the exploded one like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import split, col, explode, lit, expr

# create new df with product = 'no delimiter in rev' and quantity= 0
df1 = df.withColumn("product", lit("no delimiter in rev")) \
    .withColumn("quantity", lit(0))

# create another df by exploding the product/quantity structure and revenue=0
df2 = df.withColumn('product', split(col("product"), "\\|")) \
    .withColumn('quantity', split(col("quantity"), "\\|")) \
    .withColumn("product_quantity", explode(expr("arrays_zip(product, quantity)"))) \
    .selectExpr("product_quantity.*", "0 as revenue")

# union the 2 data frames
df1.union(df2).show()

#+-------------------+--------+-------+
#|            product|quantity|revenue|
#+-------------------+--------+-------+
#|no delimiter in rev|       0|      3|
#|no delimiter in rev|       0|      9|
#|                  a|       1|      0|
#|                  b|       1|      0|
#|                  b|       3|      0|
#|                  c|       2|      0|
#+-------------------+--------+-------+
```

Comment: thanks for your insights. Currently for `quantity` part after exploding and running few calculation the DataFrame I am creating which is equivalent to your `df2` in solution is `df2=df.groupBy('some entries').agg(countDistinct('id').alias('unique_count'),sum('quantitys').alias('sum_quantity'))` and then `df1` of your solution is just `df2=df.withColumn('sum_revenue',lit(0).cast(DoubleType()))` so instead of this if I use your `df1` then it is not taking the aggregate revenue from revenue column. any insights?

Comment: @think-maths I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do here. Surely if you do new aggregations and change the logic it won't work as in the solution above. I think this might be a new question :)

Comment: Thanks @blackbishop I will create a new question in case I am not able fix the problem with complete details